# How to find the Hamiltonian density for electromagnetic field? And, how to solve the stress tensor for electromagnetic field?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, hamiltonian-formalism, field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

How to find the Hamiltonian density for electromagnetic field? And, how to solve the [stress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell_stress_tensor) [tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor) for electromagnetic field?

Comment: Solve = calculate explicitly?

Comment: yes, exactly :)

Comment: Use Noether's theorem. This leads to a non-symmetric stress tensor and there is a standard procedure to symmetrise it. Standard text book material - see Landau and Lifshitz "Classical Theory of Fields". Lots of fun if you are doing it for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Pages 39 and 40 of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1001.1330) should provide a partial answer. You may need to read pages 35-39 first to understand the procedure.